# Spring Batch repeats job on null returned

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-batch

I am developing application that processes excel files and creates database queries from them.

BatchConfigBase.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchConfigBase {
    protected final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    protected final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    protected final ApiWriter apiWriter;

    @Value("${app.queries-batch-size}")
    protected int queriesBatchSize;
    @Value("${spring.batch.job.concurrency.limit}")
    protected int concurrencyLimit;

    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor excelTaskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(concurrencyLimit);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

ExcelBatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ExcelBatchConfig extends BatchConfigBase {

    private final AmfDataProcessor amfDataProcessor;

    public ExcelBatchConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ApiWriter apiWriter, AmfDataProcessor amfDataProcessor) {
        super(jobBuilderFactory, stepBuilderFactory, apiWriter);
        this.amfDataProcessor = amfDataProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<AmfData> amfReader() { return new AmfExcelItemReader();}

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("handleExcelAmfJob")
    public Job handleExcelAmfJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("handleExcelAmfJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(handleExcelAmfStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step handleExcelAmfStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("handleExcelAmfStep")
                .<AmfData, String>chunk(queriesBatchSize)
                .reader(amfReader())
                .processor(amfDataProcessor)
                .writer(apiWriter)
                .taskExecutor(excelTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

}
```

AmfExcelItemReader.java

```
@Component
public class AmfExcelItemReader extends AbstractExcelPoi<AmfData> implements ItemReader<AmfData>, StepExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmfExcelItemReader.class);

    private int amfDataIndex = 0;

    private String excelFilePath;

    List<AmfData> amfDataList;

    @Override
    public AmfData read() {

        AmfData amfData = null;

        if(!amfDataList.isEmpty()) {

            if (amfDataIndex < amfDataList.size()) {
                amfData = amfDataList.get(amfDataIndex);
                LOGGER.info(amfData.toString());
                amfDataIndex++;
            } else {
                amfDataIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        return amfData;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String filePath , List<AmfData> aList) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("No need to implement this method in the context");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        excelFilePath = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getString("excelPath");
        String path = new FileSystemResource(excelFilePath).getFile().getPath();
        try {
            amfDataList = read(path, new AmfDataItemRowMapper());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Cannot read the excel file: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I expected that when the `AmfExcelItemReader` will return `null` the processig will be over, but it repeats from the beginning, only the second `null` stops the processing for good.

I am sure that there has to be 2 `null` returned because when I always `return null` in the `AmfExcelItemReader` only 2 rows are being processed.

Is there a configuration i should seek to make it work properly (only one `null` to stop the processing)?

Comment: This seems to be related to your implementation of `ItemReader`. The processing should stop when the reader returns `null` for the first time.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine but what is the `ItemREader` lacking? I thought that the Spring Batch after noticing `null` stops the processing. And all the suggested implementations of custom `ItemReader` look like mine.